# Can I use conditional format to check 2 dependent cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column A and Column B shouldn't have a value simultaneously.
What condition do i need to highlight the cells in A and in B when both of them have values on the same row? (values are numbers if that helps)

P.S.

I have a helper column already:

```
=IF(AND(A3>0,B3>0),"fix","ok")
```

And i paint col A and col B based on `=cellname="fix"`.

In the end I was just wondering if i can shove the helper formula in the formula rule it self and ditch the helper column.

Comment: is there a reason you want to avoid the helper column? You can just hide it if you don't want it to show

Comment: One of the tech geeks I know suggested it being easy. If he is not blowing hot air I thought I could learn something useful. He is the kind of person that wont tell anyone even if he knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without helper formula too.

Just select your data, go to home - conditional formatting - new rule and select "use a formula to..."

Here enter e.g. this formula:
`=COUNT($A2:$B2)>1`

[image]

Of course you can keep your original logic too, or use another one, there are plenty of ways to check whether both of the cells contain numbers.

If you have already the helper column (in column C), then you can even use this formula:
`=$C2="fix"`

What's important is the correct use of relative and objective references. (`$` sign before the column letter).

Answer (score 1):

This is done by a two step process. Make a named equation to test if the two cells are equal and then apply it to the conditional format

- Select cell C1
- open name manager (on formula ribbon or use Alt I-N-D)
- make a name with it equal to =$a1=$b1 (Flag is the name in my example)
  [image]

then in the conditional format, choose use a formula, select your format and then use =Flag

[image]

Comment: Check ps on main thread.